# VSCode extension When clause not working in the collapsed folder state

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to get a VSCode extension that add a context menu to be selective and only show when the folder that is right-clicked in the explorer tree has a specific name.

My initial attempt was:

```
"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceFilename === components",
```

This works most of the time. But I found an edge case where it doesn't. If the `components` folder only has 1 child and you expand it VSCode presents it in a weird inline view. When it does this, the context menu doesn't appear because the `resourceFilename` is that of the child.

[image]

I can get the menu to show in the edge-case by doing

```
"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && (resourceFilename === components || resourceDirname =~ /\\/components$/i)"
```

But this will also trigger on the child folder of `components`

Inspecting the Context keys via the command palette reveals

- `resource` is the child folder
- `resourceDirname` is `/components`
- `resourceFilename` is the child.

But weirdly as long as I right-click the `components` folder the command triggered receives it as the resource on the command. I'm wondering if the `resource` is actually incorrect in this case?